# Magento - How to add discounts to Check/Money orders?

Tags: magento, checkout, promotions, discount

I've asked around and google'd but still nothing.

I want to be able to offer a 10% (or wtv) discount to anyone that opts out to pay directly through Wire Transfer or Check.

Can this be accomplished with Magento?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions for this problem:

1. client side solution using javascript.  You calculate the the discount price in javascript and send the new price to paypal. The advantage is easy to implement, but the discount code might be seen by others because the password is in the javascript.  Refer to http://icode4you.net/how-to-create-a-coupon-discount-for-paypal-buttons
2. server side solution.  Yo calculate the discount price on the service side which allows you to validate the discount code on the server which is more secure.  And the server side code send the updated price to paypal using PHP or other supported programming language depending on your website. Refer to: [Coupon Code For Paypal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134133/coupon-code-for-paypal-express-checkout).